# Break parent, top variables in iframe to prevent frame busting, but still access functions of parent

Tags: javascript

I am loading a website's content in an iframe through a proxy on my server. If I add this javascript at the top of the file,

```
var top = "";
var parent = "";
```

I can successfully prevent the website from frame busting. How can I do this and still access functions in the parent window, like this:

```
parent.my_function('this is called from inside the iframe');
```

Comment: Maybe you want to delete those `var`s, and the redundant `window.*` assignments.

Comment: @MaxArt: You can't delete `var`s. And on older IE, you can't delete *any* `window` properties (even though you should be able to).

Comment: @ nathan: Note that if you're at global scope, `var top` **is already** a `window` property. And also note that `var window.top` is a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks, edited the question to with these changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at all sure overwriting those variables necessarily prevents frame busting, but if it's working for you, presumably to access `parent` you can do something like this:

```
(function() {
    var oldParent = window.parent;

    window.parent = "";
    // ...
})();
```

...and access `oldParent` within the function.

---

Separately, note that

```
var window.top = "";
```

and

```
var window.parent = "";
```

...are both syntax errors. You use `var` to declare *variables*, not properties of named objects.

If you're at global scope, `var top` would create a property on `window` if there weren't already one, but if there's one already (and there is), it's a no-op and the `var` portion is ignored entirely (the assignment portion is still processed). Absent syntax errors, your four lines boil down to:

```
top = "";
parent = "";
```

or

```
window.top = "";
window.parent = "";
```

...which are equivalent if `top` and `parent` exist on `window` (and they do).

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest thing is to store the `top` and `parent` values to variables that you only know.

For example:

```
window.__myTopWindow = window.top;
window.__myParentWindow = window.parent;
window.top = window.parent = null;
```

Of course, one can iterate through the window object to discover what properties are Window objects. In this case, you may want to reassign your scope, or use Crowder's solution.